# Rotating a plane in 3D Space

Tags: 3d, rotations

I have a plane defined by 3 points. I want to rotate that plane so that it will be possible to change the orientation of the plane in any dimensions. For example, what I want to do is converting this:

[image: image1]

To this:

[image: image2]

How can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: What was the first "this" supposed to be? In any event: it should be easy if you have the Hessian normal form.

Comment: Which is supposed to be the rotation axis?

Comment: Just rotate the points; the plane will follow.

Comment: @tomasz how can I do so?

Comment: @enzotib I did not determine such an axis yet. I need a formulation, the rest I can do.

Comment: @user13791: I understood that you have the rotation given somehow and can apply it to points. If you don't, then I don't know what you actually want. To put it simply: what is the input you have, and what is the output you want to get?

Comment: I want to redefine the position of the three points I have, around an axis. So, the result will be a rotated plane.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I finally found an answer. The method I should have used is [Rodrigues' Rotation Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula)

Now I have another problem with it though. :)